# How to convert .eap file?

Tags: uml, converters, enterprise-architect, xmi, staruml

I have a situation here:

I have a `.eap` file and i have a tool available i.e., **StarUML**. I need to import the `.eap` file contents into StarUML.

Basically, i need to know how can i convert the `.eap` to some format to import into **StarUML**.(StarUML takes `.mfg` and `.xmi` as import)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.eap` files I'm familiar with are [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/).

There may be another approach, but I suspect you'll need to get a copy of EA and open your file.  Whatever models it has in it, open each and right click on the model, you'll see an `Import/Export` menu.  You can then export `.xmi` format.

Comment: I dont have a EAP software currently, i got an .eap file; i will not be able to open it. How can we do that using a converter, any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: I have no knowledge of any converters.  They've got a 30 day trial. I'd try downloading the trial copy and see if it has the export feature enabled.

Comment: Thanks...waiting for you to reply on a positive note...:)

Comment: @GOK Dennis did reply on a positive note.  Hope you took his advice.

Comment: You can also rename them to .mdb and open them in access, but interpreting the data and binary formats might be in violation with the licence agreement

Answer (score 1):

You can open and edit eap files with **MS Access**.

For EAP files created in EA version 12.1 it is Access 2007.

[Here](https://leanpub.com/InsideEA/read) is an overview of the internal structure.